# App crashes when I use pull down to refresh in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
var refresh:UIRefreshControl!
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        refresh = UIRefreshControl()
        refresh.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to load Recipes")
        refresh.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("loadData")), for: .valueChanged)
        self.tableView.addSubview(refresh)

        loadData()
    }

func loadData() {

// My code here
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        [weak self] in
                    self?.tableView.reloadData()
                    self?.refresh.endRefreshing()
                }        
    }
```

I tried using `#selector` as well but it didn't work. I have been trying many things from google but just the app gets crashed.

Comment: Please update your question with the error message and the stack trace from the crash.

Comment: Unrelated but please dump `[weak self]`. `DispatchQueue` closures never cause retain cycles. The recommended *selector* syntax is `#selector(loadData)`, no quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to add `UIRefreshControl` to a table manually:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    refresh = UIRefreshControl()
    refresh.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to load Recipes")
    refresh.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loadData), for: .valueChanged)

    self.tableView.refreshControl = refresh

    loadData()
}
```

It's hard to say whether this is the rason of the crash though.

Comment: Adding #selector(loadData) and creating a function using "@objc func loadData()"  worked. Thanks.